# What should I do if my system interrupts goes over 20% of my computer?

Tags: interrupts

My computer has been stuttering and going all over the place forever, and I found out recently that it was because my system interrupts kept going all over the place, what should I do?

Comment: Interrupts indicate that hardware needs attention.  It is basically a way for hardware to get the CPU to respond to something that hardware needs, such as copying information out of a buffer that may be a limited size.  How to proceed will vary on many details, such as what operating system you're using.  Can you figure out what hardware is causing a high amount of interrupts?  Is there some software that is using that hardware?  Interrupt usage can usually be pinpointed as being related to some specific hardware or some specific software.  What to do next depends on those details.

Comment: I can't find what's causing it anywhere in my pc